# Twitter API: accessing public replies and retweets

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to sample the relative frequencies of regular tweets vs retweets vs replies in the public timeline; however, I can't seem access the latter two. Is there any way to pull down public replies and retweets using the Twitter API? (for the record, I'm using PHP, but I think this is more of an API question) Or, alternatively, is there any way to empirically determine the relative fractions of retweets/replies/neither that exist on Twitter?

**Edit:** I should have made this explicit, and I apologize: the problem resides in the fact that the API seems to have eliminated replies and retweets from the `statuses/public_timeline` REST call, leaving only regular tweets. My question, then, is whether or not there is a way to access public replies and retweets in addition to regular tweets, given that this particular method call does not seem to work. I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to get those frequences for live status updates, you could consume Twitter's [Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api). Since you want to use PHP, [Phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose) allows you to consume the streams easily.

From there you would just examine each status update, looking for whatever markers you like to determine whether they are retweets, replies, etc.. [Twitter Text (PHP)](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-php/) might be useful (even if you just borrow the regexes).

A quick run of the above against the "Sample" stream (~1% of public statuses) showed:

- 2,986 replies
- 1,481 retweets
- 6,706 mentions
- 10,000 tweets

Comment: This looks fantastic. I have questions pertaining to the Phirehose package itself, but this may not be the appropriate place for those. Aside from that, this looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract that information parsing the tweets text looking for "RT @XXXX" or "@XXXX" patterns.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I believe retweets and replies were specifically taken out of the "statuses/public_timeline" REST call, leaving only tweets. At least, whenever I make that call, all I get back are regular tweets. I should have made this explicit in the question: I'm looking for how I can get a feel for these frequencies given that "public_timeline" doesn't seem to do it.